# get a match with regexp and pass it to a file doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get an URL in a text and write the URL into a file.

I use this code:

```
message = $stdin.read 
test = message.match('http:\/\/(.*?)$')

File.open('test.txt', 'w') do |f2|  

f2.puts "#{test}"
end
```

This text is in the message variable:

```
Die Spende muss vom Empfänger sowie Sender per E-Mail bestätigt werden. Um die Spende zu bestätigen klicke auf folgenden Link:
http://server.nitrado.net/deu/donations/verify/18074/4f8b31ac-5400-424f-917c-4dcec3529f03
```

But in the textfile appears this:

```
http://server.nitrado.net/deu/donations/verify/18074/4f8b31ac-5400-424=
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the message you read has the contents you think it has. Taking out the read from `$stdin` and using a string literal instead, I see expected results from the match:

```
message = "Die Spende muss vom Empfänger sowie Sender per E-Mail bestätigt werden. Um die Spende zu bestätigen klicke auf folgenden Link:
http://server.nitrado.net/deu/donations/verify/18074/4f8b31ac-5400-424f-917c-4dcec3529f03"
=> "Die Spende muss vom Empfänger sowie Sender per E-Mail bestätigt werden. Um die Spende zu bestätigen klicke auf folgenden Link:\nhttp://server.nitrado.net/deu/donations/verify/18074/4f8b31ac-5400-424f-917c-4dcec3529f03"

test = message.match('http:\/\/(.*?)$')
=> #<MatchData
 "http://server.nitrado.net/deu/donations/verify/18074/4f8b31ac-5400-424f-917c-4dcec3529f03"
 1:"server.nitrado.net/deu/donations/verify/18074/4f8b31ac-5400-424f-917c-4dcec3529f03">

"#{test}" # or test.to_s
=> "http://server.nitrado.net/deu/donations/verify/18074/4f8b31ac-5400-424f-917c-4dcec3529f03"
```

The final `=` on your matched result indicates to me the input may be in some format that breaks long lines, ending them with `=`. eg:

```
message = <<EOM
Die Spende muss vom Empfänger sowie Sender per E-Mail bestätigt werden=
. Um die Spende zu bestätigen klicke auf folgenden Link:
http://server.nitrado.net/deu/donations/verify/18074/4f8b31ac-5400-424=
f-917c-4dcec3529f03
EOM

test = message.match('http:\/\/(.*?)$').to_s
=> "http://server.nitrado.net/deu/donations/verify/18074/4f8b31ac-5400-424="
```

Regexp meta-char `.` matches any character except newline `[^\n]` which explains why the capture stops where it does with this input.

Comment: The input is an email directly passed by maildrop to the script. I assume thats the problem... I'll try to manage the email with the mail gem if there is no other solution thanks for your help!